# SqlAlchemy Instrumented List delete

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes like:

```
Base = declarative_base() 

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique = True)

class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Users.id'))
    sent = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    
    user = relationship('User', backref=backref('orders'))

    def __init__(self, user=None, sent=False):
        self.user = user
        self.sent = sent
```

When I execute the following code :

```
u = session.query(User)[0]
o = Order()
u.orders.append(o) 
session.commit()
```

SqlAlachemy issues an insert statement on the orders table. When I execute :

```
del u.orders[1]
session.commit()
```

sqlalchemy issues an update statement on the orders table setting user_id to NULL.

I need SqlAlchemy to issue a delete statement and the records to disappear from the database, not just being set to NULL. I've tried setting the cascade='save-update' keyword argument in the backref call, but did not succeed. I thing there must be some keyword argument configuration to achieve this, but I could not find it yet.
How could I reach the explained behaviour ? Namely, the issue of delete statements on the child tables?

Comment: Read [Cascades](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html) section of documentation, and you need to add `delete-orphan` value to your configuration.

Comment: I worked !. I also added delete option like SqlAlchemy warn suggests. I defined: user = relationship('User', backref=backref('orders', cascade='save-update, delte-orphan, delete') and it works as I need.